# Null Related Error - The argument type 'String? Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart

The same code works in the tutorial video, not sure what is happening here. I think this is related to null safety.

I did try applying ? in this solution, but I was not able to reach a solution that works. When I apply the ? method, the validation wont' work.

How to solve this issue and build the project.

This is what I get when I run the solution
[image]

This is the video URL having this sample  https://youtu.be/nFSL-CqwRDo
[image]

This is my full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Coding with Curry',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: FormScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FormScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //FormScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormScreenState createState() => _FormScreenState();
}

class _FormScreenState extends State<FormScreen> {
  String _name = "";

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _buildName() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return "Name is Requried";
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String value){
        _name = value;
      },
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Form Demo"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                _buildName(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Submit",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {
                      if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                        return;
                      }

                      _formKey.currentState.save();

                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

When I apply the null in the solution, I am not able to write the validation code
[image]

Comment: I suspect you're correct about null safety, and to be honest it's very likely the case that your tutorial video would be in an older version of Flutter and/or Dart.  I believe all you particularly need to do is just declare those parameters (for "validator:" and "onSaved:") with "String?" instead of just "String".  In fact, your "_name" variable may also need to be String? ..... or perhaps you'll just need to check for null in your logic, and set "_name" accordingly.  I've dabbled a little in Flutter, but I've not yet specifically come up against what you're dealing with here

Comment: The video is from 2019.  Null safety was enabled by default in March 2021.

Comment: Of course, knock yourself out with some reading on null safety  https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: I did try applying ? in this solution, but I was not able to reach a solution that works. When I apply the ? method, the validation wont' work.

Comment: @Craig Can you take a look at the question now.

Comment: @jamesdlin  Can you take a look at the question now.

Comment: Well, I think now you do need to do some reading on that link that I commented.  As I said, in my Flutter dabbling I've not yet used any particular commands that use null-safe String (or otherwise) parameters.  So you've essentially found yourself at a spot where you need to migrate some non-null-safe code to null-safe code.  I don't have an immediate answer to that.  However, you might also google some different phrases about flutter null safety, and chances are you might find something shorter to read (than the Dart docs) that will get you over the line.

Comment: As the error says, you need to check for null, e.g. `if (value == null || value.isEmpty)` or `if (value?.isEmpty ?? true)`.

Comment: try using `validator: (value) { }`

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada your suggestion is not clear.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks. working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use the `?` symbol you are saying that the variable can be null, so you can just check if it's null first, eg:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  //const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Coding with Curry',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: FormScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FormScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  //FormScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormScreenState createState() => _FormScreenState();
}

class _FormScreenState extends State<FormScreen> {
  String _name = "";

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _buildName() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return "Name is Requried";
        }
      },
      onSaved: (String? value){
        _name = value!;
      },
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Form Demo"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                _buildName(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Submit",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                        return _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      }
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The exclamation mark (eg, `_name = value!;`) tells the compiler that you know this nullable variable is never null. You'll see a runtime error if it actually is null.

You might also find this interesting: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

Comment: This also solved my issue, if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {  }

Comment: That definitely works too but I figured the _if null_ [operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators) wasn't as readable if you just learned about nulls.

Answer (score 4):

**Error:**

You get the error because `validator` expects a function with the parameter type nullable string (`String?`) but you're passing it as non-nullable string (`String`). For example:

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (String value) {}, // Error
)
```

---

**Solution:**

The fix is to either provide `String?` or just omit the string.

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (String? value) {}, // No error
)
```

or

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (value) {}, // No error
)
```